# Calculate probability of t distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Z is normal probability distributions and W is $\chi^2$ with degree of freedom 8, and independent.

I need to find a in $\Pr(|Z/ \sqrt{W/8}| > a) =0.05$

We know that:

$\Pr(T>t_{\alpha,n})= \alpha$

is t distributionwith $n$ is degree of freedom

$\Pr(t_8 > a $ and $t_8 <-a )=0.05$ by definition of absolute

$\Pr(t_8 > a )=0.05$

$\Pr(t_8 > a )= 0.025$

$\Pr(t_8>t_{\alpha,n})= 0.025$

$t_{\alpha,n}= t_{0.025,8}=2.306$

is this right?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thankyou, Yes I need to find a , I forgot about Z and W, I added the detail. yes they are independent of another, what do you mean by missing division sign?

Comment: Where you wrote $\Pr(|Z \sqrt{W/8}| > a)$ I suspect you meant $\Pr(|Z / \sqrt{W/8}| > a). \qquad$

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Yes, there is division sign,  I'm sorry I forgot the sign, I edited my post again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $Z$ is standard normal and, independently, $W \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(df=8),$
(as suggested by @AaronMontgomery) so that $T = Z/\sqrt{W/8} \sim \mathsf{T}(df = 8),$
you want probability 0.025 in each tail of the
t distribution.

In R, `qt(.975, 8)` returns quantile 0.975, which is 2.306004, as you say. (You can likely find approximately this value in a t table in the column headed .025 and row df = 8.)

[image]